# There is a time delay in my todolist, its not uploading data quickly to the localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on building a todo list, I got an update i.e. adding the data to the localstorage so that if the tab is refreshed the data is retrieved from localstorage, The problem is that when the second task gets added the first gets uploaded to the localstorage

```
  functionToSetLocalStorage () {
  console.log(this.state.items);
  }

  addItem(e) {
  if (this._inputElement.value !== "") {
      
      var newItem = {
        text: this._inputElement.value,
        key: Date.now()
      }
      
      console.log(this.state.items); 
      this.setState((prevState) =>{
        return {
         items: prevState.items.concat(newItem)      
      }
      }, this.functionToSetLocalStorage);
           
                  
          console.log(this.state.items);
          this._inputElement.value = ""; 
      }  
      
      e.preventDefault();
      localStorage.setItem('todoEntries',JSON.stringify(this.state.items));
  }
```

Can anyone help me with why is there a delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous function
try adding  `localStorage.setItem('todoEntries',JSON.stringify(this.state.items));` in your setState function before return new state.

```
    this.setState((prevState) =>{
       localStorage.setItem('todoEntries',JSON.stringify(prevState.items.concat(newItem) ));
       return {
         items: prevState.items.concat(newItem)      
       }
     }, this.functionToSetLocalStorage);
```

Comment: @ManthanKumbhar did u delete localStorage.setItem('todoEntries',JSON.stringify(this.state.items)); at the end ?

Comment: Yaa did that too

Comment: @ManthanKumbhar my bad I fixed JSON.stringify(prevState.items.concat(newItem)) in the answer